# Block the input of a process in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

Is there a way to block every input of a process from the standard input? I mean, not closing it's stdin file descriptor, but avoid any input that comes from the standard input device.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the close votes.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the /dev/null device to STDIN.

Comment: The question is about doing it in kernel. Could you be more elaborate on how this could be done in kernel?

Comment: How do you want to identify the process to change? I presume that you do not want to change every process.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this function in fork.c:

`static int copy_files(unsigned long clone_flags, struct task_struct *tsk)`

You need to do this just before you return from the function:

```
files_fdtable(newf)->fd[0] = NULL
```

This is the way it could be done. But take it with a pinch of salt!